# Boot Acer Aspire S3-391 from SD card

Tags: boot

I have installed and able to boot from SD card on my Acer Apire 1830T. Because of that I bought a 64 GB SD Card. However, a couple of weeks ago the PC did not work. I took it to repair.

In the mean time I really need a computer to use. So I bought the Acer Aspire S3-391. However, I cannot boot the PC from the SD card.

Can some kind soul out there help? Please.

Comment: You probably done it, but do you have your BIOS set to boot from the SD card?

Answer (score 1):

According to Acer, the Acer Aspire One netbook can not boot from sd card.
Although it can boot from USB, network, or internal hard disk.

Please see Acer's website concerning this subject:

http://acer.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/351/~/can-my-acer-aspire-one-boot-off-of-the-sd-card-reader%3F

You should probably check that the F12 boot menu is enabled in BIOS however, and try it again for from the boot menu.  Failing that, you could install grub on a USB device and use that to boot Ubuntu on the SD card.